# Как с помощью Jest проверить что был вызван alert

Tags: javascript, jest

Как с помощью Jest проверить что после нажатия кнопки был вызван alert c определенным текстом?

Попыталась сделать вот так:

```
  it('should display an alert when the user tries to add empty value', () => {
    jest.setTimeout(100000);
    page.alert = jest.fn(text => text);
    const addButtonSelector = '#root > div > div > div.ToDoInput > button';
    expect(page).toClick(addButtonSelector);
    expect(page.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Please enter a todo!');
  })
```

Но тест Failed, потому что алерт никогда не был вызван. Хотя на самом деле алерт вызывается.

Answer (score 0):

```
it('should handle the click event', () => {
      window.alert = jest.fn();
      const output = shallow(
        <Link title="mockTitle" url="mockUrl" />
      );
      output.simulate('click');
      expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Кликнули по ссылке!');
    });
```

Попробуйте один из вариантов.

1. Вместо window.alert написать global.alert
2. Добавить в обьект globals обьект window в package.json вашего проекта

   ```
   "jest": {
     "verbose": true,
     "preset": "react-native",
     "setupFiles": ["./jest/setup.js"],
     "testRegex": "(/tests/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(ts|tsx|js)$",
     "transformIgnorePatterns": [
       "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|lottie-react-native)"
     ],
     "globals": {
       "window": {}
     }
   }
   ```

3.В файле где вы пишете тест

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom'
const { window } = new JSDOM()
global.window = window
```

Comment: Вылезла ошибка "window is not defined". Если что, в проекте используется JS + React + Jest + Puppeteer.

Comment: Попыталась заменить window.alert на page.alert - не помогло. Посмотрите изменения в посте пожалуйста.

Comment: Отредактировал ответ

Comment: Вариант 3 - ругается, говорит, что только в модули можно импорт добавлять

Comment: window.alert - ругается что window is not defined

Comment: global.alert - ругается точно так же в конце теста, что алерт не был вызван ни разу.

Comment: При добавлении window в package.json всё равно ругается что not defined.